# Is there another quantum deformation of sl(2)?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

By looking at defining relations of standard deformation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, which are:

$$
[E,F] = \frac{q^{H}-q^{-H}}{q-q^{-1}}, \quad [H,E] = 2E, \quad \text{ and } \quad [H,F] = -2F,
$$

some questions come around.

For example, one can check that Jacobi identity is satisfied, but it would be also satisfied if one considers an arbitrary function $Fun(D)$ instead of the original one $\frac{q^{H}-q^{-H}}{q-q^{-1}}$.

I know that for the algebra to be quantum, the conditions of Hopf algebra have to be enjoyed.

But still, can we imagine another deformation for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$? Or there is a theorem which says that it is the only deformation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is $Fun(D)$?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but if you are including Lie element $H$ in the generators along with group-like $q^{\pm H}$ (for which you would also need to specify the multiplicative commutation relations with $E$ and $F$), you are getting not the "standard" deformation, but rather a certain extension. Having said that, there are 2- parameter "quantum groups", where the relations involve $p$ and $q$.

Comment: To Alex,
Under $Fun(D)$ was meant any arbitary function of generator $D$. It is easy to check that Jacobi identity is satisfied as well. 
(I do realize that it is not enough for algebra to be quantum)

Comment: To Victor,
You are right, but multiplicative commutation relations with $E$ and $F$ are nothing else than rewrting of two of three defining relations. 
How are you going to add second parameter of deformation $p$?
Could you please write it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your second question, on other possible deformations of $sl(2)$:

There have been various studies on (multi-parametric) deformations of Lie algebras -as has already been mentioned in the comments to the OP- during the last decades:
 An example of a $2$-parameter deformation $sl_{pq}(2)$ which leads to a quantum group is given by: 
$$
[H,E_{\pm}]=\pm E_{\pm}, \ \ \ [E_+,E_-]=\frac{q^{2H}-p^{-2H}}{q-p^{-1}}
$$
where $E_-$ stands for $F$,up to a suitable rescaling and $p$, $q$ are complex parameters.
 (setting $p=q$ and rescaling the generators produces the $q$-deformation described in the OP as a special case). You can find more details at [arXiv:math/0506539](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506539v1), where this deformation is studied and it is proved that it admits a class of infinite dimensional representations with no analogue in the undeformed or in the $q$-deformed case.
Another -similar- example can be found in the article: [A two-parameter deformation of the universal enveloping algebra of $sl(3,C)$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01555521), by J.F. Cornwell. A detailed discussion on the hopf structure of the deformed algebra and its implications on the usual hopf structure(s) of the undeformed algebra is also included.
In [Introduction to quantum algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9409012.pdf), by M.R. Kibler, two parameter deformations such as $u_{pq}(2)$ and $u_{pq}(1,1)$ are studied: their hopf algebraic structures are investigated and their realizations (that is: homomorphisms or isomorphisms) with two parameter deformations of the Weyl algebras and the angular momentum algebras are used as a tool of investigating their representations.

Comment: Much appreciated!
A small research showed that it is indeed the case -- to find appropriate Hopf structure for another deformations. It was the case of q-deformed oscillator, for instance.